# Using local packages with Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Say I have two projects (`project-a` and `project-b`) and I wanted to include project-a into project-b without uploading project-a to stackage.  How could I publish the package locally and include it into project-b like so?

```
# package.yaml for project-b
dependencies:
- base      >= 4.7 && < 5
- project-a == 2.0.0.0
```

Comment: Look for `extra-deps` in the official documentation: http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/

Comment: @arrowd Is this the preferred method for doing this?  Also, how would I package up project-a as a zip or tar file?

Comment: @arrowd I found the `sdist` command, so I know how to package it.

Answer (score 6):

Special thanks to @arrowd for pointing me in the right direction.  This is an answer to my question but if someone else has a better one I will accept it.

In **project a** run the command

```
> stack sdist
```

that will package your project up into a tarball and show you what directory it is in.

Then go to **project b** and add the following to the `stack.yaml` file under the `extra-deps` section

```
extra-deps:
- archive: /path/to/project-a/tar/file
```

and in your `package.yaml` file under dependencies

```
dependencies:
# other dependencies
- project-a == 2.0.0.0
```

then run

```
> stack build
```

and project-a will be included in project-b.

Comment: Can also add the project-a as a build-depends in the .cabal file as needed.